# Does a proper Email ALG (i.e. Email-Proxy) alter/remove the local Email-Header information?

Tags: email, proxy, header

Does a proper Email ALG (i.e. Email-Proxy) alter/remove the local Email-Header information so the recipient does NOT get information about the locally used IP addresses?

Example:

```
Received: from mail.example.com (10.53.40.198) by
 mail.example.com (10.53.40.197) with Microsoft SMTP Server
 (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256) id
 15.1.2375.31; Fri, 4 Nov 2022 09:54:08 +0100
```

In the best case, I would want to have this information removed or replaced by the info of the ALG.

Answer (score 2):

- Are there email gateways which hide these internal information? - Yes.
- Do all email gateways hide these information? - No.
- Should the latter ones be considered a "proper Email ALG"? - There is no defined standard for the features of a "proper" Email ALG, so this depends on your specific expectation of what being "proper" means.